# Cycle through text in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make it so that when I click on a button the text will change. I have been able to achieve that, however, I'd like to go down a list of text. For each button click, the text should change to something new.

I can only get it to change once. I'm not sure how to go about doing so tho. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){
        $("#text").text("I have changed!");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have a `current` counter and an array of the `texts`.

- **Step 1:** Add the texts in an array.
- **Step 2:** Initialize a count.
- **Step 3:** Programmatically add the first value.
- **Step 4:** Increment the count.
- **Step 5:** Update the text.
- **Step 6:** Make sure you don't run of boundaries. So use modulus.

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Step 1: Add the texts in an array.
  var texts = ["Hello, World!", "Hello, Praveen!", "Hello, StackOverflow"];
  // Step 2: Initialize a count.
  var count = 0;
  // Step 3: Programmatically add the first value.
  $("#text").text(texts[count]);
  $(".button").click(function() {
    // Step 4: Increment the count.
    count++;
    // Step 5: Update the text.
    // Step 6: Make sure you don't run of boundaries. So use modulus.
    $("#text").text(texts[count % texts.length]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text"></div>
<button class="button">Change</button>
```